# Gdalwarp creates a "perspective drawing" effect rather than an ortho-rectified image

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, orthorectification

I have been happily using the "utilities as libraries" functionality of gdal 2.1+ to ortho-rectify an image. First I use `gdal.Translate` to convert the source file to a geotiff, and then I warp it to (supposedly) match the coordinates. Here is the code:

```
tmp = gdal.Translate("tmp1.tif", src_img, format="GTiff", outputSRS="EPSG:4326", GCPs=gcpList)
warped = gdal.Warp("warped1.tif", tmp, srcSRS="EPSG:4326", dstSRS="EPSG:4326")
```

However, when I open `warped1.tif` at the end, I get something that looks like this:

[image]

The strange thing, though, is that when I just open `tmp.tif`, which has NOT been warped by `gdal.Warp`, in OpenEV (which seems to warp geotiffs on its own) I get a perfectly orthorectified image (though when I open `tmp.tif` in windows photo viewer it looks exactly like the source image):

[image]

Am I missing something obvious here?

**EDIT:** I suppose part of the reason for my question is that I don't understand on a deep level what `gdal.Translate` does. I know that it makes the image file into a GeoTiff based on the ground control points that I provide, but how is the location information stored in the GeoTiff? Is it just stored as a bunch of ground control points, or is it stored as a homography matrix along with a coordinate which could then be used to reproject the image to the correct perspective?

Whichever it is, I am assuming that both gdalwarp and OpenEV use this information to warp the image. What I find strange is that OpenEV does it perfectly while `gdalwarp` does not.

Comment: Since I can't post three links in the question, here is a link to the original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LadlL.png

Comment: Use some projected CRS like your UTM zone for the output if you want to show the result with a non-GIS viewer.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new to this--how would I go about doing that? And by "the result" do you mean `tmp.tif` or `warped.tif`?